# How to copy the "first" row of a spark data frame to another data frame? Why does my minimal example fails?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Basic Problem :**

I want to copy the "first row" of a Spark Dataframe `sdf` to another Spark dataframe `sdfEmpty`.

I do not understand what goes wrong in the following code.
Hence I am looking forward for a solution and an explanation what fails in my minimal example.

**A minimal example :**

```
// create a spark data frame
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val sdf = Seq(
 (1, "a"),
 (12, "b"),
 (234, "b")
).toDF("A", "B")

sdf.show() 
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
|  2|  b|
|  3|  b|
+---+---+

// create an empty spark data frame to store the row
// declare it as var, such that I can change it later
var sdfEmpty = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], sdf.schema)

sdfEmpty.show()
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
+---+---+

// take the "first" row of sdf as a spark data frame
val row = sdf.limit(1)

// combine the two spark data frames
sdfEmpty = sdfEmpty.union(row)
```

**As `row` is:**

```
row.show()
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
+---+---+
```

**the exspected result for `sdfEmpty` is:**

```
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
+---+---+
```

**But I get :**

```
sdfEmpty.show()
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  2|  b|
+---+---+
```

**Question:**
What confused me is the following: Using val row = sdf.limit(1) I thought I created a permanent/ unchangeable/ well defined object. Such that when I print it once and add it to something, I get the same results.

**Remark:** (thanks a lot to Daniel's remarks)

I know that in the distributed world of scala there is no well defined notion of "first row". I put it there for simplicity and I hope that people struggling with something similar will "accidentially" use the term "first".

What I try to achieve is the following: (in a simplified example)
I have a data frame with 2 columns A and B. Column A is partially ordered and column B is totally ordered.
I want to filter the data w.r.t. the columns. So the idea is some kind of divide and conquer: split the data frame, such that into pieces both columns are totally ordered and than filter as usual. (and do the obvious iterations)

To achieve this I need to pick a well defined row and split the date w.r.t. row.A. But as the minimal example shows my comands do not produce a well defined object.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you share output of `println(sdf.rdd.partitions.size)` ?

Comment: @moriarty007 The output of println(sdf.rdd.partitions.size) is 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @Christian you can achieve this result by using take function.
>   take(num) Take the first num elements of the RDD. It works by first scanning one partition, and use the results from that partition to estimate the number of additional partitions needed to satisfy the limit.
>   here the code snippet.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

scala> val sdf = Seq(
 (1, "a"),
 (12, "b"),
 (234, "b")
).toDF("A", "B")

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql._

scala> var sdfEmpty = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], sdf.schema)

scala> var first1  =sdf.rdd.take(1)

scala> val first_row = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(first1), sdf.schema)

scala> sdfEmpty.union(first_row).show
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
+---+---+
```

for more about take() and first() function just read [spark Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD).let me know if you have any query related to this.

Comment: Hi mahesh gupta, (and daniel)
stupid question: 
using `take` gives me an array which I then have to convert to a data frame. which looks to me like a extra step.

comparing this to `collect()`, which approach would be more efficient. in the end the question is just part of a function, which I will call in millions.

Unfortunately I am new to scala and have no idea how the create a big and random example on my own.

requirements : column A is partiall ordered (e.g. array with ordering defined by subset) and column B is totally ordered.  Precisely I don't know how to create column A.

Comment: @Christian please read this  https://umbertogriffo.gitbooks.io/apache-spark-best-practices-and-tuning/content/dont_collect_large_rdds.html you will get to know take vs collect

Answer (score 3):

Spark is distributed, so the notion of 'first' is not something we can rely on. Dependently on partitioning we can get a different result when calling `limit` or `first`.

To have consistent results your data has to have an underlying order which we can use - what makes a lot of sense, since unless there is logical ordering to your data, we can't really say what does it mean to take the first row.

Assuming you want to take the first row with respect to column A, you can just run `orderBy("A").first()`(*) . Although if column A has more than one row with same smallest value there is no guarantee which row you will get.

(* I assume scala API has the same naming as Python so please correct me if they are differently named)

Comment: Dear Daniel, thanks for the answer. I know that in the distributed world of spark there is not a well defined ordering of the rows in the data set. That's why I used quotation marks. Moreover in my particular use case I just need to pick one arbitary but fixed element w.r.t. some ordering.

What confused me is the following:
Using
`val row = sdf.limit(1)`
I thought I created a permanent/ unchangeable/ well defined object.
Such that when I print it once and add it to something, I get the same results.

Comment: Hi Christian, ```.limit``` is just a transformation - it does not get evaluated until your run it with an action, such as ```show``` or ```collect```, so dependently on the context it can return different value. If you want to use this row consistently you can ```.collect``` it to driver and use as a local variable or ensure your transformations have deterministic ordering with ```.orderBy```

Comment: Hi Daniel!
Thanks for the explanation, but my code actually was already : 
`val row = sdf.limit(1)
row.show()
sdfEmpty = sdfEmpty.union(row)`

so I did not thought using show() will start the evaluation. 
I am a bit afraind of using collect(), as it will crashes if the data does not fit into the drivers memory, does it?

I used orderBy to in a previous step and did not mentioned it, to keep the example as small as possible.

However I am up for any style tips which help me improving asking questions and I am also glad for your aswer as I am using Scala since 1 week and ...

Comment: ```.collect``` will fail only if the result of your query is larger than memory - which in case of reading a single row is pretty much impossible. I'm glad I could help - please accept the answer and upvote if you found it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answer as it contains the solution suggested by Daniel. Once I am through literature provided mahesh gupta or some more testing I'll update this answer and give remarks on the runtimes of the different approaches in "real life".

**Basic Problem :**

I want to copy the "first row" of a Spark Dataframe `sdf` to another Spark dataframe `sdfEmpty`.

As in the distributed world of spark there is not a well defined notion of first, but something similar might be achieved due to `orderBy`.

**A minimal working example :**

```
// create a spark data frame
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val sdf = Seq(
 (1, "a"),
 (12, "b"),
 (234, "b")
).toDF("A", "B")

sdf.show() 
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
|  2|  b|
|  3|  b|
+---+---+

// create an empty spark data frame to store the row
// declare it as var, such that I can change it later
var sdfEmpty = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], sdf.schema)

sdfEmpty.show()
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
+---+---+

// take the "first" row of sdf as a spark data frame
val row = sdf.limit(1).collect()

// combine the two spark data frames
sdfEmpty = sdfEmpty.union(row)
```

**The `row` is:**

```
row.show()
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
+---+---+
```

** and the result for `sdfEmpty` is:**

```
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
+---+---+
```

**Remark**: Explanation given by Daniel (see comments above) `.limit(n)` is a transformation - it does not get evaluated until an action runs like show or collect. Hence depending on the context it can return different value. To use the result of `.limit` consistently one can `.collect` it to driver and use it as a local variable.